# hadoop datanode failed to start with invalid location

Tags: hadoop

all the services are running except datanode. when i start datanode, i get the errors below.

```
> ************************************************************/
2017-09-05 10:19:06,339 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2017-09-05 10:19:06,675 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /data1/hdfs/dn should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2017-09-05 10:19:06,675 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /data2/hdfs/dn should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2017-09-05 10:19:06,679 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /data3/hdfs/dn should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2017-09-05 10:19:07,441 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: Login successful for user hadoop/hzes@HZ.DATA.COM using keytab file /opt/keytab/hadoop.keytab
2017-09-05 10:19:08,208 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid dfs.datanode.data.dir /data1/hdfs/dn : 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/data1/hdfs/dn does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:598)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:811)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:588)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:425)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.checkDir(DataNode.java:2516)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2558)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2661)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.SecureDataNodeStarter.start(SecureDataNodeStarter.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
...............


2017-09-05 10:19:08,218 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid: "/data1/hdfs/dn" "/data2/hdfs/dn" "/data3/hdfs/dn" 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2661)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.SecureDataNodeStarter.start(SecureDataNodeStarter.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
2017-09-05 10:19:08,221 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2017-09-05 10:19:08,233 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

my relative configuration:

```
 <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
 <value>/data1/hdfs/dn,/data2/hdfs/dn,/data3/hdfs/dn</value>
```

why? i runinig all services with root

when i change the configuration to another location(eq: /home/hadoop), it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. What are the permissions and owner of `/data1/hdfs/dn,/data2/hdfs/dn,/data3/hdfs/dn` directories.
2. You don't have to mention `/hdfs/dn/`, it will automatically create `/dfs/dn/`.

Comment: i don't make /data1,/data2,/data3. it won't automatically make the directores?

Comment: Could you rephrase your comment, not able to understand